# External links still display wrong after turned off the "Automatically turn URLs into links" feature

Tags: channel-entries, members, url

I have a custom URL member field - "Twitterhandle" that contains a link to the member's twitter page. I use the field on single entry template page, within the channel entries tag with the following html:

```
<a href= "{Twitterhandle}">
    <img src= "/images/blog/twitter%20teal.png" width= "24px" height="24px">
</a>
```

The goal is to have a clickable image. I have turned off "Automatically turn URLs and Email Addresses into Links" feature for the Channel, but the link still displays the full text of the url and then the image, not as a clickable image.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how I can get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: Have you republished the entry?

Comment: That template code should work. Can you just put {Twitterhandle} on its own nearby in your template and confirm the output of that?

Comment: What's the field type? i suggest you use a text input, with formatting to set to none. 
After you've done that, reopen the entry, confirm the input is as should be, and re-save.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code that you posted in your questions.